# Running several times the same command with several arguments after a pipe

Tags: shell, pipe, tee

I have a key (of random binary data) that gets generated by `get_key`.

And with this key, I can do several things with my encrypted files. For example, I can decrypt them.

`get_key | tee >(decrypt file1) >(decrypt file2)`

I would like to know how I could generalize that to `n` files where the files are given as `FILES=file1 file2 file3 file4 file5`.

At the moment, I can see two solutions:

1) Compute a string and `eval` it

2) replace decrypt by a recursive function `f` that calls decrypt does `tee >(decrypt A[0]) | f ("${A[@]:1}")` (it decrypts the first element and calls itself recursively) if the array is not empty and nothing if it is.

I wanted to know if you had a nicer way to doing that (note that I do not want the key to be written to a file or a variable, so loops aren't an option).

---

Edit: I'll use it in https://github.com/xavierm02/combine-keys

Comment: Given what you've said in comments about wanting to feed a key to `cryptsetup`, I think you're [barking up the wrong tree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should carefully think about your security requirements (what are the risks? what are the attack vectors?) and infrastructure (when are you doing this — presumably in the boot process? what information and tools do you have available?) and ask one or more higher-level question about that.

Comment: I want to protect all data at rest with a password and a keyfile and be able to back up the keyfile using secret sharing. This implies that I can't encrypt the keyfile with the password because otherwise, I would have to replace all the backups everytime I changed the password. The only other way to require both is to derive a key from both (atm using xor). And I have any tools I want available since I can just add hooks to make update-initramfs add things to the ramfs. Aside from the derivation method, there is no real choice, unless I want to mess with dm-crypt directly, and I don't.

Comment: @Gilles : I asked a new question there: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16109/encrypt-hdd-with-keyfile-and-password-and-allow-backing-up-the-keyfile-with-secr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make FIFOs in a loop and have your `decrypt`s wait for them to be written to:

```
for i in "${A[@]}";do
    mkfifo /tmp/"$i"_fifo
    decrypt "$i" </tmp/"$i"_fifo &
done
getkey | tee >/dev/null /tmp/*_fifo
rm -f /tmp/*_fifo
```

Comment: You're writing the keys to several files. I want to use the key to decrypt several files..

Comment: @xavierm02 Sorry, I wasn't paying attention. Does this help?

Comment: @xavierm02 Please don't forget to mark the answer 'Accepted' if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: I will :) I'm just making sure it works first. And since the program isn't as simple as I made it look, it's taking time :)

Answer (score 5):

Given your use case, there's no point in starting to run the decryption until the key is fully generated, so you don't need to launch the `decrypt` processes until `get_key` has finished. Therefore a pipe has no advantage, you might as well store the output of `get_key` somewhere and use it afterwards.

Storing the output in a variable is the easiest way. However, since this is binary data that can contain null bytes, **this only works in zsh, not in other shells**. If you're worried about security, don't be: an attacker who can observe the content of the variable can also run `get_key` and watch its output.

```
key=$(get_key)
for file in $FILES; do
  print -rn -- $key | decrypt $file
done
```

In other shells, you can use a temporary file. Be sure to make it readable only by you. If the temporary file is on an on-disk filesystem, then there is a small risk that the key could be leaked if the server's hard disk was stolen at the wrong time. If the file is on an in-memory filesystem, there is no such risk.

```
key_file=$(umask 077; mktemp)
get_key >"$key_file"
for file; do
  decrypt "$file" <"$key_file"
done
rm "$key_file"
```

If you don't want to use a temporary file and don't have zsh, you can use another language such as Perl or Python.

```
perl -e '
    $key = `get_key`;
    foreach (@ARGV) {
        open KEY, "|-", "decrypt", $_ or die $!;
        print KEY $key or die $!;
        close KEY or die $!;
    }'
```

If you have no better language than a POSIX shell or ksh or bash, and can't use a temporary file, then you'll need to fall back to piping into `tee` (or do some hairy encoding and decoding). To cope with the variable number of outputs, you can [create one fifo per output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128550), or build and `eval` a string containing the necessary `<(…)` (beware of the tricky quoting).

Comment: `get_key` prompts for a password so he won't get anything. And I'm not trying to protect data from someone having a virus on my computer or access to it while it's on. I'm trying to protect it from someone who would try to recover the data from the computer while off. And that someone wouldn't care what permissions your file has or where it was written. I did not know about that feature of ksh so thank you for that. But I still like the idea of never having the whole key written linearly in memory so I'll do it Joseph's way. +1 though :)

Comment: @xavierm02 Warning: your security model is flawed. If the key is in the memory of `get_key`, or of `decrypt`, or in a pipe, it's still in memory! Putting it in the memory of zsh or perl doesn't make things worse. To counter someone who would steal the disk, as I indicate, make sure that the temporary file is on an in-memory filesystem. (An encrypted filesystem would also do fine.)

Comment: It's not. get_key asks for a password, calls a C program (xor) with via stdin (but the password is in memory). The C program returns the xor of the key and the keyfile it reads (and I don't think he even has all the keyfile in memory). Which is piped to cryptsetup. In short `decrypt device` means `promt_password | xor keyfile | cryptsetup luksOpen -d - device`. I don't think it will ever be all in memory, or at least not in the part of the process I control.

Comment: The keyfile is obvously on a usb key that doesn't remain near the computer obviously. Worst case senario: cryptsetup waits for the whole key and this way of doing it is as secure as yours. Best case senario: it doesn't and the key is never all in memory and the places where it is placed is then used for the rest of it so recovering the whole key from memory is impossible.

Comment: @xavierm02 No, the key is quite obviously in the memory of the C program, since it's producing the key as output. Where else did you think the key was, if it wasn't in memory? Oh, and also, ouch! Xor is not a good way of masking a key with a password. Since you're using cryptsetup, use its key file feature. You're falling into the trap of rolling your own cryptography and doing a much worse job than the standard tools.

Comment: The keyfile is quite long. The C program reads a character from the keyfile, one from stdin and then outputs the xor of those two chars. It doesn't keep it in memory. It might stay a bit longer because of the output buffer but then it gets transferred to cryptsetup. And I don't think the buffer is big enough to retain the whole key. | Why is it not a good way? If you concatenate them, your resulting key has a regognizable pattern: random stuff followed by human-readable characters. If you xor them, you have no information on the resulting key.

Comment: The key file feature only allows a keyfile, not a key file and a password so I have to produce a keyfile that depends on my keyfile and the password anyway. That's what I'm doing but I have it read the file from stdin. | I'm thinking of trying to switch to your way of doing it because otherwise, making a "change password" thing is really annoying: prompting when you have pipes everywhere and background processes is a bit hard.

Comment: @xavierm02 This is too long to explain in a comment, but in a nutshell: xor requires a password that's as long as the key, and doesn't spread entropy well because the password isn't uniformly random. You should use a [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), with key stretching on the password.

Comment: @xavierm02 Regarding input to the C program, the input is in memory. You might xor one copy with the key, but even after that there are probably other copies lying around, until the program exits. And the key itself of course is in cryptsetup's memory, and in the kernel itself. You can't protect against an attacker who can get a RAM dump (except by arranging for the key to remain solely in the CPU cache, but that's hard).

Comment: I don't get why the entropy of the password needs to be spread. The fact that the keyfile is random makes the output random, whether you know the password, just how it looks or nothing about it. Think of it that way: It would be secure if I gave it just the password. But I want to require the keyfile too so I XOR the password with the keyfile. The entropy of the result is strictly larger than the entropy of the password alone. There could be a problem is it sliced the password and used different parts of it for different things but it doesn't: it uses a key derivation function on it.

Comment: (it=cryptsetp). About the memory, I still don't understand. The password is in memory and I XOR it but reading the file character per character and outputing the result as soon as it's ready. Imagine a 10GB keyfile. I will never have it all in memory but will still be able to compute the xor since it needs just one character at a time. Anyway, not having it in memory isn't a requirement. It's just something that might improve security.

Comment: What's the reason for using `print -rn` instead of `echo -n`? And do I really need to do `$(get_key)` instead of `get_key`?

Comment: @xavierm02 You need `$(…)` to store the result into a variable instead of displaying it on the terminal. `print -rn --` is in case the value looks like an option to `echo`. But all this is for zsh anyway, which is not something you're likely to have available at the point where you want to run `cryptsetup`.

Comment: @xavierm02, you are indeed [rolling your own crypto, which is a **very very very very** bad idea](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/96753).